# Parse XML with Boost access and populate property tree

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, boost, boost-propertytree

I have XML file:

```
<expressions>
    <addition id="1">
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
    </addition>
    <subtraction id="2">
        <minuend>3</minuend>
        <subtrahend>2</subtrahend>
    </subtraction>
    <multiplication id="3">
        <factor>5</factor>
        <factor>6</factor>
        <factor>8</factor>
    </multiplication>
    <division id="4">
        <dividend>54</dividend>
        <divisor>9</divisor> 
    </division>
</expressions>
```

Need to parse it and provide the result like another XML:

```
<expressions>
    <result id="1">9</result>
    <result id="2">1</result>
    <result id="3">240</result>
    <result id="4">6</result>
</expressions>
```

Currently I'm investigating the BOOST in area of ptree and read_xml
Please advise where additional information could be found?
Thanks in advance

My current investigation results are:

I have the class which defines Expression with virtual function which evaluates expression, lower on inheritance tree this function should be overridden and implemented in context of expression type.

```
class AbstractExpression
{
public:
    AbstractExpression(ExpressionType aType){}
    virtual ~AbstractExpression() {}

    // Evaluates expression (must be overrided by child)
    virtual int  evalExpr() const = 0;

};
```

Inherited classes are `additionExpression`, `substractionExpression`, `multiplicationExpression`, `divisionExpression`.

Besides this I have implemented methods of data manipulation in every inherited class.

At the end I've wrote some code, which counts this XML:

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree pt;
    read_xml("/PATH_TO/valuator.xml", pt);
    const ptree & expressions = pt.get_child("expressions");
    BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type & currExpr, expressions){
        std::string readExprType = currExpr.first;
        std::cout << "currExpr = " << readExprType << std::endl;

        if (readExprType == "addition") {
            AbstractExpression *addExpr = new additionExpression();
            BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type & additionNodeEl, currExpr.second){
                std::string val = additionNodeEl.second.data();
                ((additionExpression*)addExpr)->addVal( atoi(val.c_str()) );

            }
            std::cout << "addition result = " << addExpr->evalExpr() << std::endl;
            delete addExpr;
        } else if (readExprType == "multiplication") {
            AbstractExpression *multExpr = new multiplicationExpression();
            BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type &multNodeEl, currExpr.second) {
                std::string val = multNodeEl.second.data();
                if (!val.empty())
                    ((multiplicationExpression*)multExpr)->addVal( atoi(val.c_str()) );
            }
            std::cout << "multiplication node result = " << multExpr->evalExpr() << std::endl;
            delete multExpr;
        } else if (readExprType == "subtraction") {
            AbstractExpression *substrExpr = new substractionExpression();
            BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type &substNodeEl, currExpr.second) {
                std::string elTypeName = substNodeEl.first;
                std::string val = substNodeEl.second.data();
                if (elTypeName == "minuend") {
                    ((substractionExpression*)substrExpr)->setMinuend( atoi(val.c_str()) );
                } else if (elTypeName == "subtrahend") {
                    ((substractionExpression*)substrExpr)->setSubtrahend( atoi(val.c_str()) );
                }
            }
            std::cout << "subtraction node result = " << substrExpr->evalExpr() << std::endl;
            delete substrExpr;
        } else if (readExprType == "division") {
            AbstractExpression *divExpr = new divisionExpression();
            BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type &divNodeEl, currExpr.second) {
                std::string elTypeName = divNodeEl.first;
                std::string val = divNodeEl.second.data();
                if ( elTypeName == "dividend" ) {
                    ((divisionExpression*)divExpr)->setDividend( atoi(val.c_str()) );
                } else if ( elTypeName == "divisor" ) {
                    ((divisionExpression*)divExpr)->setDivisor( atoi(val.c_str()) );
                }
            }
            std::cout << "dividend node result = " << divExpr->evalExpr() << std::endl;
            delete divExpr;
        }

    }
```

Now I need to write all these results to XML.

Comment: Sorry for message format, especially source code.

Comment: Put results into the map<int, string> and write XML as text later

Comment: Ok, but how can I get "id" from <addition id="1"> </addition>
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, use a proper XML library (TinyXML, RapidXML, PugiXML, libxml2 etc.).

If you really care only about a very specific subset of XML, here's a quick & dirty parser based on Boost Spirit V2: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65d4d844c57a1f90)**

```
namespace /*parser*/
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
        struct grammar : qi::grammar<It, ast::expressions(), Skipper>
    {
        grammar() : grammar::base_type(expressions_)
        {
            using namespace qi;

            static const lexeme_type L;

            simplevalue_ = auto_; // parses into Value, whatever it was declared as
            id_attr      = eps >> L["id"]      > '=' > '"' > int_        > '"';
            complex_attr = eps >> L["complex"] > '=' > '"' > *~char_('"') > '"';
            expr_open    = eps >> '<' >> L[lit(_r1)] > -id_attr > -complex_attr > '>';
            expr_close   = eps >> '<' >> '/' > L[lit(_r1)] > '>';

            // expression element parsing
            addition_       = expr_open(+"addition") > +subexpr_(+"item")                                  > expr_close(+"addition");
            subtraction_    = expr_open(+"subtraction") > (subexpr_(+"minuend") > subexpr_(+"subtrahend")) > expr_close(+"subtraction");
            multiplication_ = expr_open(+"multiplication") > +subexpr_(+"factor")                          > expr_close(+"multiplication");
            division_       = expr_open(+"division") > (subexpr_(+"dividend") > subexpr_(+"divisor"))      > expr_close(+"division");
            expression_     = simplevalue_ | addition_ | subtraction_ | multiplication_ | division_;

            subexpr_ = eps >> '<' >> L[lit(_r1)] > '>' > expression_ > '<' > '/' > L[lit(_r1)] > '>';

            expressions_ = eps
                > '<' > L["expressions"] > '>'
                > *expression_
                > expr_close(+"expressions");

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((simplevalue_)(expr_open)(expr_close)(subexpr_)(addition_)(subtraction_)(multiplication_)(division_)(expression_)(expressions_))
        }
      private:
        template <typename... T>
            using Rule = qi::rule<It, T..., qi::space_type>;

        // tags/primitives
        Rule<> complex_attr;
        Rule<int()> id_attr;
        Rule<ast::Value()> simplevalue_;
        Rule<ast::Id(std::string element_name)> expr_open;
        Rule<void(std::string element_name)> expr_close;

        Rule<ast::expression(std::string element_name )> subexpr_;

        // compounds
        Rule<ast::addition()>       addition_;
        Rule<ast::subtraction()>    subtraction_;
        Rule<ast::multiplication()> multiplication_;
        Rule<ast::division()>       division_;
        Rule<ast::expression()>     expression_;

        Rule<ast::expressions()> 
            expressions_;
    };

} /*parser*/
```

It parses the input into an abstract syntax tree that can be visited to evaluate the (sub) expressions. The test driver

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("expressions.xml");
    It f(ifs >> std::noskipws), l;

    try {
        ast::expressions parsed;

        grammar<It> g;
        // parsing
        bool ok = phrase_parse(f, l, g, qi::space, parsed);

        // output results
        if (ok)
        {
            eval::machine machine;

            std::cout << "<expressions>\n";
            for (auto& expr : parsed)
                if (get_id(expr))
                    std::cout << "\t<result id=\"" << *get_id(expr) << "\">" << machine.evaluate(expr) << "</result>\n";
            std::cout << "</expressions>\n";
        }
    } catch(qi::expectation_failure<It> const& e) {
        std::cout << "Expected " << e.what_ << " at '" << std::string(e.first,e.last) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
<expressions>
    <result id="1">9</result>
    <result id="2">1</result>
    <result id="3">240</result>
    <result id="4">6</result>
</expressions>
```

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42b4cb94d4c4dfb1)**

<sup>Note: doesn't handle comments, unicode, processing instructions, namespaces, PCDATA, character entity references etc. In short **This is not an XML parser**</sup>

Comment: Thanks allot, but there is another case for this task (just got update), complex nodes with flag "complex":
`
<addition id="10" complex="true">
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>
        <subtraction>
     <minuend>7</minuend>
     <subtrahend>3</subtrahend>
     </subtraction>
    </item>
</addition>
`
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: By the way, your solution generates error message while I'm trying to compile:
simpleVal.cpp:21:30: error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const lexeme_type' (aka 'const expr<proto::tag::terminal, term<boost::spirit::tag::lexeme>, 0>') requires a user-provided default constructor
    static const lexeme_type L;                            ^
1 error generated.
What boost version do you use?

Comment: @OleksandrHryhorchuk that's `clang` for you. And it's right. Although there is a defect report against the standard for this AFAIR. (As you notice in my answer, it includes the initializer)

Comment: Generally I've almost done with this task, but I'm still property tree and ream_xml.
By the way, to read attributes (was in my previous questions) wee need to:
`auto second = currExpr.second;
second.get<int>("<xmlattr>.id");`
Just to clarify for others.

Comment: @OleksandrHryhorchuk You should make that an answer. Anyways, here's a version that does the subexpressions too. Complete with AST representation now. See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65d4d844c57a1f90)** where it can be seen calculating **[these lovely expression trees](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8418839/)**: 2 and -6138.58 (Look ma! No explicit dynamic allocations).

Comment: Success with compile, however I have the expression:
<multiplication id="13" complex="true">
    <factor>
  <addition>
   <item>2</item>
   <item>3</item>
   <item>4</item>
   </addition>
    </factor>
    <factor>6</factor>
    <factor>
    <multiplication>
 <factor>3</factor>
 <factor>4</factor>
 <factor>5</factor>
 <factor>10</factor>
 <factor>56</factor>
    </multiplication>
</factor></multiplication>
There should be result 1814400, but I've got 1.8144e+06

Comment: @soho I'm really, really, really thankful for you for this solution!
Closing this question as answered by you! How can I do that (i'm new here)

Comment: You found it :) It still makes sense to add your solution to read attribute values with Boost PropertyTree. That seems like pretty rare information (I had never heard of it and assumed it wasn't a feature)